# How to compare two DataSet using HashSet in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am adding two tables to a DataSet and I want to check if they are equal.

The code I have tried is :

```
SqlDataAdapter mydat = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Device_Profile_Param+'='+Device_Profile_Default_Value AS SettingsCheck From Device_Profile_Master Where Device_Profile_Name = '" + Label5.Text + "'", con); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
mydat.Fill(dt);

DataSet dset = new DataSet();
dset.Tables.Add(dt);

SqlDataAdapter mydata = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Device_Profile_Param+'='+Device_Profile_Default_Value AS Settings From Device_Profile_Master Where Device_Profile_Name = '" + For_Profile_Num.Items[i] + "'", con);
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
mydata.Fill(dt2);

dset.Tables.Add(dt2);

var hashSet1 = new HashSet<string>(dset.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value));
var hashSet2 = new HashSet<string>(dset.Tables[1].Rows.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value));

var result = hashSet1.SetEquals(hashSet2);
if (result == true)
{
found = 1;
}
```

I am getting a error **DataSet cannot be cast as ListItem**. Kindly help.

Comment: Is it necessary cast row to ListItem? Can you write like this: `dset.Tables[0].Rows.Select(x=>x["ColumnName"].value)`

Comment: I tried it says DataSet Row doesn't have any Select method.

Answer (score 0):

define some column name when you are adding it to HashSet...

```
System.Collections.Hashtable myHashtable1 = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
                myHashtable.Add(dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column1"], myDataTable1.Rows[0]["Column2"]);
                myHashtable.Add(dset.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Column1"], myDataTable1.Rows[1]["Column2"]);

System.Collections.Hashtable myHashtable2 = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
                myHashtable.Add(dset.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Column1"], myDataTable1.Rows[0]["Column2"]);
                myHashtable.Add(dset.Tables[1].Rows[1]["Column1"], myDataTable1.Rows[1]["Column2"]);


var result = myHashtable2 .SetEquals(myHashtable1);
if (result == true)
{
found = 1;
}
```

Likewise...

Hope it helps

Comment: How do I compare after this..?

Comment: this is the way to add it to hashtable then you can compare using var result = hashSet1.SetEquals(hashSet2); only... I belive you have problem in adding DataTable to HashTable and not comparing?

Comment: Yea that's right, but in the code you have given how do I put datatable1 to hashSet1 and datatable1 to hashSet2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IEnumerable` as Follow to compare two Tables...

```
IEnumerable<string> table1Value= dset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(x => (string)x[ColumnName]); 

IEnumerable<string> table2Value= dset.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(x => (string)x[ColumnName]); 

IEnumerable<string> ChangedValue = table2Value.Except(table1Value);
```

if `ChangedValued` is null or empty then both tables are same

Comment: Not the same, there is a case table1Value contains all values of table2Values including some other values.

Comment: Yes I agree,then we will have to write the Except in Both the ways and check if both results are empty or null